# HTTP Headers for Unknown Content-Length

Tags: .net, http, binary, streaming, http-headers

I am currently trying to stream content out to the web after a trans-coding process. This usually works fine by writing binary out to my web stream, but some browsers (specifically IE7, IE8) do not like not having the Content-Length defined in the HTTP header. I believe that "valid" headers are supposed to have this set.

What is the proper way to stream content to the web when you have an unknown Content-Length? The trans-coding process can take awhile, so I want to start streaming it out as it completes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try sending them in chunks along with [`Transfer-Encoding:`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.41) [`chunked`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1). More details in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

**Update** as per the comments, here's an example how a "ChunkedOutputStream" in Java may look like:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2395192;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ChunkedOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private static final byte[] CRLF = "\r\n".getBytes();
    private OutputStream output = null;

    public ChunkedOutputStream(OutputStream output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int i) throws IOException {
        write(new byte[] { (byte) i }, 0, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        writeHeader(length);
        output.write(CRLF, 0, CRLF.length);
        output.write(b, offset, length);
        output.write(CRLF, 0, CRLF.length);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        output.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        writeHeader(0);
        output.write(CRLF, 0, CRLF.length);
        output.write(CRLF, 0, CRLF.length);
        output.close();
    }

    private void writeHeader(int length) throws IOException {
        byte[] header = Integer.toHexString(length).getBytes();
        output.write(header, 0, header.length);
    }

}
```

...which can basically be used as:

```
OutputStream output = new ChunkedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
output.write(....);
```

You see in the source, every chunk of data exist of a header which represents the length of data in hex, a CRLF, the actual data and a CRLF. The end of the stream is represented by a header denoting a 0 length and two CRLFs.

**Note:** despite the example, you actually do **not** need it in a JSP/Servlet based webapplication. Whenever the content length is not set on a response, the webcontainer will automatically transfer them in chunks.

Comment: I tried using chunks, and Firefox would lock up when receiving them. I am transferring binary data, do I have to convert it to hex to use chunks? Are there any .NET libraries available for this?

Comment: No, you don't need to convert. And I would expect .NET to handle this automatically if you do not specify the content length upfront.

Comment: Click the link behind `chunked` and the wikipedia link to get an idea how it should look like. I don't do .NET, so I can't give much, but I can give a Java based example in flavor of an extended `OutputStream`. Let know if you'd like to see it.

Comment: I'll take the Java example if you can give it. I can do a little translation to .NET I think. I'm especially curious to know if I can send binary data. So far I've only seen Hex, and overall I've seen very few examples of how chunked transfers work at all.

Comment: In a Java servlet, you just send data without setting the content length. This switches to chunked encoding. And yes, binary works.

Comment: Thanks for the great example! I believe I can get it from here.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks again so much. I've posted my C# code below.

Comment: Note that chunked transfer is supported by HTTP 1.1. It won't work for clients such as wget which are 1.0. Always check client's headers.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a follow up to BalusC's excellent post, here is the code I am using in C#. I am chunking data manually directly to an HTTP output stream, after receiving data from the STDOUT on a process.

```
int buffSize = 16384;
byte[] buffer = new byte[buffSize];
byte[] hexBuff;
byte[] CRLF = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n");

br = new BinaryReader(transcoder.StandardOutput.BaseStream);

//Begin chunking...
int ret = 0;
while (!transcoder.HasExited && (ret = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffSize)) > 0)
{
    //Write hex length...
    hexBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ret.ToString("X"));
    e.Context.Stream.Write(hexBuff, 0, hexBuff.Length);

    //Write CRLF...
    e.Context.Stream.Write(CRLF, 0, CRLF.Length);

    //Write byte content...
    e.Context.Stream.Write(buffer, 0, ret);

    //Write CRLF...
    e.Context.Stream.Write(CRLF, 0, CRLF.Length);
}
//End chunking...
//Write hex length...
hexBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(0.ToString("X"));
e.Context.Stream.Write(hexBuff, 0, hexBuff.Length);
```