# How to get pdf with popup of save or open in JSF as in PrimeFaces Export

Tags: java, jsf, export

How to get pdf with popup of save or open option in JSF as in PrimeFaces Export

Comment: If you want to force download a file, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9394237/149872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following header to the response

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourFileName.pdf"
```

from this header browser will know that this response is an attachment and it will do the default action configured for the browser