# How to download file in JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to create JSF page which downloads Glassfish log files from the directory `/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/`

I found [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileDownload.jsf#) Primefaces tutorial. I'm interested is there any possible way to make the same result with pure JSF?

Comment: You can create your own Download-Servlet which serves you whatever data you want, it only has to be accessible (on server side) from within your application server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stream a file download in a JSF backing bean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at JCA, and look around for a good JCA adapter that provides file i/o.  if you're working in a Java EE app, you probably want the transactional advantages that a properly implemented JCA adapter can/should provide (ACID, rollback, etc.)  also, using a resource exposed by the container rather than "going native" will allow deployment security to operate properly wrt touching resources outside the container (files, sockets, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

For a really simple solution, you can create a link (using [ln](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln)) to the desired log file somewhere in your web application.

```
cd /path/to/your/webapp/

ln /path/to/your/logfile.log .
```

With that you can access it directly with an URL;

```
http://yourServer/path-to-your-webapp/logfile.log
```

Comment: This is very insecure for a Web Application.