# Error Rendering View: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: jsf, download, illegalstateexception

I am creating a project in JSF and spring whose main only purpose is to generate PDF file in the browser. Everything seems fine and pdf generated too but on console i am getting this exception.Anyone have idea about this? I have searched and found that many peoples had that problem but i didn't find any solution for mine one.

```
 SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/WebPages/SearchPages/index.xhtml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3991: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

I am getting this error while creating my outputstream object

```
HTTPServletResponse response = (HTTPServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
```

Is there any problem while my creation or anyother reason? Any help would be greatly appreciable

Comment: Where is this PDF generation code being called?  The reason I am asking is because a prior Spring process or JSF rendering process may be fetching the OutputStream and writing bytes to the response before this code is executed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell JSF that you've already completed the HTTP response yourself, otherwise JSF will still continue doing the default RENDER_RESPONSE job after the action method is finished, which would result in exactly this exception, because the response is already committed.

You can do that by calling [`FacesContext#responseComplete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29) in the action method.

> ### responseComplete
>
> `public abstract void responseComplete()`
>
> Signal the JavaServer Faces implementation that the HTTP response for this request has already been generated (such as an HTTP redirect), and that the request processing lifecycle should be terminated as soon as the current phase is completed.

#### See also:

- [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean/9394237#9394237)