# Downloading zip file with IOUtils in JSF errors with "Empty response, an empty response was recieved from the server"

Tags: java, jsf, io, download, zip

I am downloading zip file from web server using Java in my jsf bean. My code works for JPEG well but not for ZIP. Here is my code.

```
private void createDownloadFile(final URL downloadUrl, final String mimeType) {
    final FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final ExternalContext context = fc.getExternalContext();
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getResponse();
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + downloadUrl + "\"");

    try{
        final OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(downloadUrl.openStream(), out);
        fc.responseComplete();
    }catch (final IOException exc){
      exc.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And this is the error: Empty response, an empty response was recieved from the server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try just to download the file using regular web browser? Put *exactly* the same URL to browser and try. What do you see?

Comment: Yes i did.I copied the URL in my web browser. I've seen the download window

Comment: Here is your sending code. What does your receiving code look like?

Comment: I become in another method the URL to the zip file from webservice

Comment: final URL downloadUrl = service.download(myList);
                if(downloadUrl != null){
                    createDownloadFile(downloadUrl, "application/zip");
                }

Comment: You should edit your post and add this info in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Empty response, an empty response was recieved from the server.*

This message is recognizeable as a XML parsing error in Chrome; the XML parser couldn't find the requested XML root element. In combination with whatever you're trying to do, this suggests that you were trying to download the file by JavaScript/Ajax. You **cannot** do this because JavaScript has due to obvious security reasons no facilities to force a *Save As* dialog with file content which is been hold in a variable.

This error message is caused because JSF ajax responses are definied to return a specific XML format, `<partial-response><update>`, etc. But if the `<partial-response>` root element is missing in the JSF ajax response, then the browser-specific XML parser will/may show this kind of error.

You need to download the file by a synchronous request instead. Remove the `<f:ajax>` or set whatever ajax-toggling attribute of the 3rd party component to `false`, such as `<p:commandButton ajax="false">`.

You don't need to worry about a page change in the browser, as you've set the `Content-Disposition: attachment` response header, the current page will just remain the same. This problem is in no way specific to Commons IO, by the way.

#### See also:

- [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean/9394237#9394237)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check and try

Comment: Yes it works, that was my problem. I had f:ajax with my h:commandLink for download.