# Export data to excel in Richfaces

Tags: richfaces

Hi I am using Richfaces 3.3 and looking for a best solution to export Data to the Screen to an Excel file. The File needs to be downloaded on user's machine. I have searched through the internet and found that POI api can do this. Looking for a best possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use Apache's `POI` api. There are lot of examples in the web which shows how to do this in `java`. Doing this in `JSF` is not very much different than that. 
Visit following links to see how to do this in `JSF2`.
[Export to Excel JSF and PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822758/export-to-excel-jsf-and-primefaces) 
[How to export rich:dataTable to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199185/how-to-export-richdatatable-to-excel)

Following example shows how to do this in `jsf1.2`

```
public void generate() {
    try {
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet1");

        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("1st Col value");
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue("2nd Col value");

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        res.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=mydata.xls");

        ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
        wb.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You need to download and add `poi-version-yyyymmdd.jar`.