# File download through datahandler object in JSF

Tags: jsf, download, liferay, portal

I want to download a file in my jsf project. At bean side I am getting object of DataHandler. I tried to search many times but I did not found anything related to it. How can I download a file through datahandler object?

```
DataHandler src = attachment.getAttachment();

ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
src.writeTo(output);
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Type", src.getContentType());            
externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=sachin.jpg");
externalContext.getResponseOutputStream().write(output.toByteArray());
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

And if anybody knows about a good tutorial on file download and file upload which describes whole process in detail would be great for me.

Comment: As to the `DataHandler` part, this is not recognizeable as part of JSF API. What API is that `DataHandler` class coming from? You should just lookup and read its documentation to fill in the missing parts. As to the JSF part, the question is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean/9394237#9394237

Comment: @BalusC When I checked my page by firebug to see the response, I  am getting that file. But I dont know why its not showing me "save as" dialog box of windows.

Comment: You mean that it's displaying it inline instead of as attachment? In other words, the download works perfectly fine, but the way how the browser deals with it is not correct?

Comment: @BalusC This is what I am getting in response header

Content-Disposition attachment;filename=sachin.jpg
Content-Length 12259
Content-Type application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8
Date Mon, 07 Jan 2013 11:51:09 GMT
Etag "4e01ce5b"
Liferay-Portal Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.0 EE SP1 (Bunyan / Build 6011 / January 13, 2011)
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-JAVAX-PORTLET-FACES-NAM... true

Comment: You've still not elaborated in detail what exactly happens instead. Is the browser displaying it inline instead of as attachment? If so, then it's just a matter of browser configuration setting. JPG files are by default associated with Firefox application itself.

Comment: @BalusC Actually I am beginner in web page development. I am not getting the term "inline" in this context. I will tell you whole thing what I understand in my project. I have commandLink for download and in bean side I have the above code. Whenever I am clicking that commanlink in server side its executing my download method correctly but at browser end its nt showing any dialog box to save it. Then I checked my webpage by firebug and in console I found that I am getting response header like above.

Comment: What are you seeing in the browser window? Is the browser showing a blank page or the sole image itself (thus, "inline")?

Comment: @BalusC Ohh I got it. Thanx BalusC for your quick replies. Its not showing blank page or that image. Its showing the same screen where I have clicked that download link as nothing has happened.:(

Comment: Oh, are you sending an ajax request or so?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22325/discussion-between-kush-sahu-and-balusc)

Comment: @BalusC This is my code at jsf side. I just found that p:commandlink is by default ajax=true 
<p:commandLink value="Download" action="#{submittedIncidents.fetchAttacment(incident.srcObject.incidentID)}" />
Is that the reason why I am not getting any dialog box?

Comment: Well, that was already answered in the bottom of the link I posted in my 1st comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friend solve for me this. Actually liferay environment was the problem. Earlier I was setting a portlet response. So he made a different servlet for download.