# Save dialog box in jsf

Tags: jsf, download, jsf-1.2

I have created pdf using IText library
Now I want when the user clicks on the button ,it should prompt a save dialog box to the user to allow to browse the destination location to store the file.

Now My code looks like

```
    Document document = new Document();
    try {

                    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.reset();  
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ABC.pdf");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");  
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);  
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());

        document.addTitle("Form");
        document.addSubject("Form");

        document.open();

        Paragraph paragraph12 = new Paragraph("FORM",

        FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA,

        18, Font.BOLD, new CMYKColor(0, 255, 255, 17)));

        Chapter chapter1 = new Chapter(paragraph12, 1);
        paragraph12.setSpacingAfter(25);
        paragraph12.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        document.add(paragraph12);
        // Centered

        Chunk underline = new Chunk(AppNo);
        underline.setUnderline(0.2f, -2f);

        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Application No:");
        paragraph.add(underline);
        paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        paragraph.setSpacingAfter(20);
        document.add(paragraph);
        // Left
        paragraph = new Paragraph("To,");
        paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        document.add(paragraph);
        // Left with indentation
        paragraph = new Paragraph(
                "");
        paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        document.add(paragraph);

        Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph(
                "Subject: ");

        paragraph2.setSpacingAfter(15);
        paragraph2.setSpacingBefore(15);
        paragraph2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        paragraph2.setIndentationRight(50);
        document.add(paragraph2);



        Paragraph paragraph3 = new Paragraph("I  ");
        String laName=deaclarationOpr.getDeclarationDetailsobj()
                .getLaName();
        if(laName!=null){
        Chunk name = new Chunk(laName);
        name.setUnderline(0.2f, -2f);
        paragraph3.add(name);
        }
        paragraph3.add("  request you to process the Application  ");
        paragraph3.add(underline);
        paragraph3.add("  for product  ");


        String productName=deaclarationOpr
                .getDeclarationDetailsobj().getProductName();
        if(productName!=null){
        Chunk product = new Chunk(productName);
        product.setUnderline(0.2f, -2f);
        paragraph3.add(product);
        }
        paragraph3
                .add("");

        paragraph3.setSpacingAfter(15);
        paragraph3.setSpacingBefore(15);
        paragraph3.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        paragraph3.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph3.setIndentationRight(50);
        document.add(paragraph3);

        Paragraph paragraph4 = new Paragraph(
                "");





        String code=deaclarationOpr
                .getDeclarationDetailsobj().getAdvisorCode();
        if(code!=null){
        Chunk advisorCode = new Chunk(code);
        advisorCode.setUnderline(0.2f, -2f);
        paragraph4.add(advisorCode);
        }
        paragraph4
                .add("");

        paragraph4.setSpacingAfter(15);
        paragraph4.setSpacingBefore(15);
        paragraph4.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        paragraph4.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph4.setIndentationRight(50);
        document.add(paragraph4);

        Paragraph paragraph5 = new Paragraph(
                "");

        paragraph5.setSpacingAfter(15);
        paragraph5.setSpacingBefore(15);
        paragraph5.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        paragraph5.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph3.setIndentationRight(50);
        document.add(paragraph5);

        Paragraph paragraph6 = new Paragraph(
                "");

        paragraph6.setSpacingAfter(15);
        paragraph6.setSpacingBefore(15);
        paragraph6.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        paragraph6.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph6.setIndentationRight(50);
        document.add(paragraph6);

        Paragraph paragraph7 = new Paragraph("Date:      ");
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        // get current date time with Date()
        Date date = new Date();
        paragraph7.add(dateFormat.format(date));
        paragraph7.setSpacingBefore(15);
        paragraph7.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph7.setIndentationRight(50);
        paragraph7.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        document.add(paragraph7);

        Paragraph paragraph8 = new Paragraph("Name of the Proposer:      ");

        String propoer=deaclarationOpr
                .getDeclarationDetailsobj().getProposerName();
        if(propoer!=null){
        Chunk proposerName = new Chunk(propoer);
        proposerName.setUnderline(0.2f, -2f);
        paragraph8.add(proposerName);
        }
        paragraph8.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        paragraph8.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph8.setIndentationRight(50);
        document.add(paragraph8);

        Paragraph paragraph9 = new Paragraph("Place:      ");
        paragraph9.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph9.setIndentationRight(50);
        paragraph9.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        document.add(paragraph9);


        document.close();
```

context.responseComplete();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Following filters are defined in web.xml

```
<filter>
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
            <param-value>20000000</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>enable-cache</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And the above code is written in the method of Backing Bean class

and invoked

```
<tr>
<td align="center"><a4j:commandButton
value="Print" styleClass="button"
action="#{declarationBB.convertToPdf}"></a4j:commandButton></td>
</tr>
```

I get below in the new page

```
%PDF-1.4 %��3 0 obj <>stream x��V����Ժ@��rs�0��m|셒F6[�T���H[��E D'��7��
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the PDF to the HTTP response instead of to a local file.

Replace

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:/Files/ABC.pdf"));
```

by

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"ABC.pdf\"");
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());

// ... (your PDF building code here)

context.responseComplete();
```

and invoke it in action method associated with download button. The `Content-Disposition` header with value of `attachment` will force a *Save As* dialogue (*unless* the browser is configured to automatically open PDF files in Adobe Reader!).

#### See also:

- [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean/9394237#9394237)

---

**Update**: as per your update, you're invoking the download by ajax.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Print" styleClass="button" action="#{declarationBB.convertToPdf}"></a4j:commandButton>
```

This won't work. You can't download files by ajax. Ajax is executed by JavaScript, but it has due to obvious security reasons no facilities to programmatically force a *Save As* dialogue with asynchronously obtained/generated content in some variable. Make it a normal request instead. Use `<h:commandButton>` instead.

Comment: It is redirecting to other page and displays somthing in encrypted form (���=('VKz�q�/"��]����!� 1v&���Xw~s5:;?�ܮ���c�u��eA���Y���)

Comment: That's not encrypted. That's just the binary PDF content presented as text. Apparently you didn't set the proper content type header so the browser didn't understood what to do with it.

Comment: I have set "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"ABC.pdf\""

Comment: I said content type, not content disposition. It's the `response.setContentType("application/pdf");` line as in my answer. By the way, how exactly is the action invoked? Another possible cause would be that it's invoked in an inappropriate manner. Do you have any servlet filters on the request which manipulate the response headers? That would be another possible cause. It would also be helpful if you post which response headers the browser ultimately got.

Comment: Response header: Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="ABC.pdf"Content-Length:1907Content-Type:application/pdfDate:Tue, 08 Jan 2013 06:36:22 GMTServer:Apache-Coyote/1.1X-Powered-By:JSF/1.2

Comment: As per the update, use a normal ajax-less `<h:commandButton>`. You cannot download files by ajax. This is also mentioned in the bottom of my answer of the "See also" link