# FireFox adds txt extension to file downloaded through HttpServletResponse

Tags: jsf

I am using `HttpServletResponse` wrapped with JSF 2.1 in order to make a download button. Following the instructions of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394237/870122

Since I want to download a `csv` file, I use the following headers:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
ec.responseReset();
String fileName = "MyFile.csv";
ec.setResponseContentType("text/plain");
ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

The download completes successfully with both IE9 and FF, but with the second I see that the browser adds a ".txt" extension that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should try by setting the response content type to `text/csv`

Comment: Thanks, your solution works perfectly, although I couldn't find an authoritative reference to this content type around...

Comment: Try looking at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and more specifically [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)