# Send HTTP POST request to external site using <h:form>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to send a HTTP post request to another server using `<h:form>` component.

I can send a POST request to an external site using HTML `<form>` component, but `<h:form>` component does not support this.

```html
<form action="http://www.test.ge/get" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="test"/>
    <input type="submit" value="CALL"/>
</form>
```

How can I achieve this with `<h:form>`?

Comment: @BalusC ahh, thanks for clearing it up. question seemed kinda confusing to me :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to use `<h:form>` to submit to another server. The `<h:form>` submits by default to the current request URL. Also, it would automatically add extra hidden input fields such as the form identifier and the JSF view state. Also, it would change the request parameter names as represented by input field names. This all would make it insuitable for submitting it to an external server.

Just use `<form>`. You can perfectly fine use plain HTML in a JSF page.

---

**Update**: as per the comments, your *actual* problem is that you have no idea how to deal with the zip file as obtained from the webservice which you're POSTing to and for which you were actually looking for the solution in the wrong direction.

Just keep using JSF `<h:form>` and submit to the webservice using its usual client API and once you got the ZIP file in flavor of `InputStream` (please, do not wrap it a `Reader` as indicated in your comment, a zip file is binary content not character content), just write it to the HTTP response body via `ExternalContext#getResponseOutputStream()` as follows:

```
public void submit() throws IOException {
    InputStream zipFile = yourWebServiceClient.submit(someData);
    String fileName = "some.zip";

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    ec.responseReset();
    ec.setResponseContentType("application/zip");
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();

    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int length = 0; (length = zipFile.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        try { output.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        try { zipFile.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
    }

    fc.responseComplete();
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean/9394237#9394237q)

Comment: but in html <form> how to use managed bean, i want to use <p:selectOneMenu> component and want to this was dinamicali. <p:selectOneMenu>  component contents i get from database and how to get using html?

Comment: Just use plain HTML. Another option is to send a redirect in bean's action method. Your concrete problem is still hard to understand. Is it that you want to have the look'n'feel of PrimeFaces components?

Comment: I want to call web service, that work only http post method. When i call web service from browser e.i submit form parameters i get the zip file from web service and there zip is downloaded. i try to call web service java side but then i get BufferedReader object and do not know how to convert there object in zip file and download.

Comment: Oh, if that's your *real* problem, just write it to `ExternalContext#getResponseOutputStream()`. See updated answer. You should only fix it such that you don't wrap it in a `Reader`, but an `InputStream`. Otherwise you will get a corrupt file.

Comment: very thank to help, i do not know FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext(); Now i know there :) thank