# Download link encodedKeyStore

Tags: jsf-2, download

I've been generated a PKCS12 keystore through a API, but the return of the process is a KeyStore object. I need to send it, directly to the browser to be downloaded when the client send the requisition.

How can I do that?

I'm using java and jboss 5AS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`KeyStore#store()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20char%5B%5D%29) to write it out to an `OutputStream`.

```
keyStore.store(outputStream, password);
```

That's basically it. The `OutputStream` could be the one of the HTTP response. For a generic kickoff example of how to provide a file download in JSF wherein you need to integrate this line, head to this answer: [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean/9394237#9394237) Use a [content type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) of `application/x-pkcs12`.

Comment: BalusC, thank you a lot, i followed you tip and the link, and all worked fine, I'll post the code to the peoples can use it too!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
public void cadastrar () throws Exception
{       
    byte[] encodedKeyStore = controlador.cadastrar(certificadoModel);

    java.security.KeyStore keyStore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keyStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedKeyStore), certificadoModel.getPassword().toCharArray());

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

    ec.responseReset(); 
    ec.setResponseContentType("application/x-pkcs12"); 
    //ec.setResponseContentLength(contentLength); 
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + certificadoModel.getUsername() + ".p12" + "\""); 

    OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();
    keyStore.store(output, certificadoModel.getPassword().toCharArray());

    fc.responseComplete(); 
}
```