# How can I get a KeyStore from byte[] of a PrimeFaces uploaded file

Tags: java, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, keystore

I'm trying to get a `KeyStore` from PrimeFaces `UploadFile`, but this only returns a `byte[]`. How can I convert it back to a `KeyStore`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look closer at the [`KeyStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) javadoc. Next to the [`store()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20char%5B%5D%29) method taking an `OutputStream`, which you learnt in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646599/download-link-encodedkeystore), there's also a [`load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load%28java.io.InputStream,%20char%5B%5D%29) method taking an `InputStream`.

The PrimeFaces [`UploadedFile`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile.html) has according the javadoc next to the `getContents()` method returning a `byte[]` also a `getInputStream()` method returning an `InputStream`.

So, all with all, this should do:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = uploadedFile.getInputStream()) {
    keyStore.load(inputStream, password);
}
```

Lesson learnt: learn how to find and interpret the javadocs and do the math :)

By the way, if you would have had really no way to get an `InputStream` at hands, but only a `byte[]`, then you could always have wrapped it in an [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).