# XML file generation to user specified location

Tags: jsf-2, jaxb, richfaces, download

I am generating a xml file using JAXB but at present file is generated at specified location,How can i use a browse button to specify the location of folder to save the generated file.
Have tried with input type="file" of HTML but it is useful for uploading the file.Want it to do from rich faces only.

Answer (score 1):

Just write it directly to the HTTP response along with a `Content-Disposition` header with a value of `attachment`. This will force the browser to pop a *Save As* dialogue.

So, essentially all you need to do is to marshal the XML tree straight to [the output stream of the HTTP response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResponseOutputStream%28%29) instead of the output stream of the file after having set the proper headers.

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
// ...

ec.responseReset(); // Make sure the response is clean and crisp.
ec.setResponseContentType("text/xml"); // Tell browser which application to associate with obtained response.
ec.setResponseCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // Tell browser how to decode the characters in obtanied response.
ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""); // Tell browser to pop "Save As" dialogue to save obtained response on disk.
marshaller.marshal(model, ec.getResponseOutputStream()); // Look ma, just marshal JAXB model straight to the response body!
fc.responseComplete(); // Tell JSF that we've already handled the response ourselves so that it doesn't need to navigate.
```

Note: downloading a file via ajax is not possible. Remember to turn off the ajax feature of the RichFaces/Ajax4jsf command component invoking this method, if any.

#### See also:

- [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean/9394237#9394237)