# Excel file download via JSF action method results in some strange characters being prepended and complete JSP page being appended

Tags: excel, jsf, download

I am using JSF and in one of the managed bean (view scope) i have a method as:

```
public String viewReport() {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=book1.xls");

        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\soheb\\book1.xls");
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

            byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
            //copy binary contect to output stream
            while(fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
            {
                out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
            }
            fileIn.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

The excel which is getting retrieved is corrupted file. It has some strange characters above and below is the entire code of JSP. I even tried application/octet-stream for contenttype too.

I tried the same with a plain text file and i was able to open it through.

Please help me with this problem, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It has some strange characters above*

You need to [reset the response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#reset%28%29) beforehand.

```
response.reset();
```

Another possible cause is that the file being saved is corrupt by itself. E.g. saved using a `Writer` instead of `OutputStream`.

---

> *and below is the entire code of JSP*

You need to [tell JSF that you've already completed the response yourself](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29) so that it won't perform its default navigation and render response job after invoking the action method.

```
context.responseComplete();
```

#### See also:

- [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean/9394237#9394237)