# JSF bean and HTML5 canvas cooperation

Tags: html, jsf, html5-canvas

I'm making a project in JSF with Primefaces 4.0 (server Tomcat 7). I have to read an image from a MS SQL database and put a group of areas on it (every area is limited to the coordinates read from a DB too). Every single area of the image has to be a clickable "object". When user clicks on that area, the new image has to be loaded from a DB with new links put on it. According to my (rather not enough) knowledge about the JSF, there is no component allowing for something like this.

So, my idea is to:
- get the image stored in raw bytes in DB to byte array (in a bean)
- create a response with those data (according to the very first BalusC post from [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean))
- get bytes from this response by a JS (yes, don't know how...)
- read them to a  HTML5 component, draw an image with an area border using coordinates got from another response and in some way make it clickable.

I realise this solution is rather nonsense but I have completely no other idea  Could you suggest me, what would be the better way to solve my problem? I went through many Google search results and didn't find the similar one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try [Primeface's Diagrams](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/diagram/basic.xhtml)