# How to provide a file download in JSF out of the servlet context

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download

How can I download a file found out of the servlet context using Primefaces/JSF? I already know how to download a file found in the servlet context, and in a package, but will like to know how to do the download when the file is out of the servlet context.

Comment: @Gaël what I mean is getting a file found on a drive on the server where the application is deployed and make it downloadable using JSF!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is get the file as an `InputStream` and pass that stream to the response using JSF methods (`ResponseOutputStream` or something like that).

See: [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-provide-a-file-download-from-a-jsf-backing-bean)