# Unable to download the zip file after clicking confirmDialog ok button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am unable to download the zip file.
    After clicking ok button in confirmDialog I am unable to download a zip file.
    If I am not using  confirmDialog I can able to download the file.
    Could any one help me on this,

Here I added the code for the reference.

```
<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid rendered="true">
        <p:commandButton style="HEIGHT: 24px; WIDTH: 300px" id="AjaxFalse"
            value="AjaxFalse"
            action="#{testDownload.getZipFile}"
            title="AjaxFalse" rendered="true">
            <p:confirm message="Are you sure?"
                header="Confirmation"
                icon="ui-icon-alert" />
        </p:commandButton>

    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" width="500">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="text-align: center">
                    <p:commandButton value="Ok"  type="submit" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" style="width:70px;"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" style="width:70px;"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
    </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

My backingbean is

```
public class TestDownload
{
//some code here
//Downloading the zip file in jsf2.x
public String getZipFile()
    {       
    try{
    //enter code here
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
            ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Test + ".zip\"");
            ec.setResponseCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            ec.setResponseContentType("application/zip");
            //This method will generate the required file.
            new BulkloadImporter().generateIntegrationXSDs(getId(), ec.getResponseOutputStream());

            fc.responseComplete();
            return "Save";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Handling exception
        }

    }
    //some code here    
}
```

Comment: If I remove <p:confirm> tag, and adding ajax="false"for button, then its working as excepted.But I use <p:confirm> then unable to download.

Comment: I would expect a `p:confirm` and `ajax=false` combination to also work. Downloading in 'ajax=true' does not work...

Comment: Combination of the p:confirm and ajax=false also not working, for this combination control not at all going to the bean method.

Comment: So that is your problem... https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/99

Comment: Off-Topic: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-provide-a-file-download-from-a-jsf-backing-bean?lq=1 (especially the 'OmniFaces' Faces.sendFile(...) thing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is not 'download' related. Up to now (PrimeFaces 5.3/5.3.2) using a `<p:confirm...>` global dialog in combination with `ajax="false"` [does not work](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/99). The server side action in general will not be called.

There are two possible solutions:

- Don't use global mode and do the download on the button in the confirmDialog
- Use the workaround mentioned in the issue (not tested this myself)

An example of non-global usage can be found in the PrimeFaces Documentation (adapted to this case):

> **Getting started with ConfirmDialog** ConfirmDialog has two modes; global and non-global. Non-Global mode is almost same as the dialog
>   component used with a simple client side api, show() and hide().
>
> ```
> <h:form>
>   <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="PF('cd').show()" />
>   <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure about downloading this file?"
> header="Initiating download" severity="alert" 
> widgetVar="cd">
>      <p:commandButton value="Yes Sure" action="#{testDownload.getZipFile}" ajax="false"
> update="messages" oncomplete="PF('cd').hide()"/>
>      <p:commandButton value="Not Yet" onclick="PF('cd').hide();" type="button" />
>   </p:confirmDialog>
> </h:form>
> ```

Comment: Wow, 3 upvotes on an answer that could be found by just searching google, looking at the PrimeFaces issuelist and documentation.