# OmniFaces CacheControlFilter has no effect when response contains Content-Disposition header

Tags: jsf, cache-control, omnifaces, content-disposition

It seems that cache directives are not applied when the resource response contains HTTP header `Content-Disposition:inline`. When we use OmniFaces CacheControlFilter the response doesn't contain `Cache-Control` or `Expires` directive. Is it normal?

Comment: More than often, response headers are reset by code intented to stream a file download. Are you sure this isn't the case here?

Comment: Correct. there is a response.reset(); in the code

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not the default behavior.

This behavior suggests that the code responsible for streaming the file has performed a `response.reset()` in order to ensure that the response is crisp and clean. You see this often in copypaste code snippets because starters otherwise complain that the download doesn't work. For example here: [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-provide-a-file-download-from-a-jsf-backing-bean)

Given that you're using OmniFaces, you may probably find [`Faces#sendFile()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Faces) or [`FileServlet`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/servlets/FileServlet) more useful for the task of streaming a file to response. The `Faces#sendFile()` [does not](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.5.1/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/FacesLocal.java#L1649) perform a `response.reset()`, and the `FileServlet` caches by default [30 days](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.5.1/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/servlet/FileServlet.java#L120) which is controllable by overriding the [`getExpireTime()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/servlet/FileServlet.html#getExpireTime-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-java.io.File-) method.

Comment: Thanks, It will be very useful