# Providing file download in JSF like download.jsf?id=123

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to provide download links (that should also work for images in an img tag) in the style of

```
http://www.domain.example/download.jsf?id=123
```

and my solution so far looks like this: (copied from here: [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-provide-a-file-download-from-a-jsf-backing-bean) )

**GetFile.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class GetFile{

// property and getter

public void setId(String id) {

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

    ec.responseReset();
    ec.setResponseContentType(contentType); 
    ec.setResponseContentLength(contentLength);
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

    try (OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream()) {
        // Now you can write the InputStream of the file to the above
        // OutputStream the usual way.
        // ...

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    fc.responseComplete(); 
}
```

and my **download.xhtml** looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{getFile.id}" />
    </f:metadata>

</html>
```

That works so far. But when I want to add additional parameters like

```
http://www.domain.example/download.jsf?id=123&format=txt
```

then I would have to consider the order in which the parameters are set and do this in the last setter. That would work but I don't find that a very pretty solution, so my question is, is there a better way to achieve this?

Any hints are very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiating the download in a setter is in general not a very good design and should only do its main purpose, to set a variable (and maybe some checking/conversion/etc related to setting).

To start the download you should create a new method in your backing bean that handles the download and use that method. So your bean should look something like this:

**GetFile.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class GetFile {

    // properties, getter and setter

    public void download() {
        // your download code goes here
    }
}
```

This way you can use as many parameters as you want and pass them the way you did. In your **download.xhtml** you can call your bean method after passing the arguments like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{getFile.id}" />
        <!-- your other parameters come here -->
    </f:metadata>
    #{getFile.download()}
</html>
```