# Invoke Navigation and FileDownload in JSF without JS

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download, navigation

Im currently looking for a solution to invoke a pagenavigation from "foo.xhtml" to "bar.xhtml" and starting a download dialogue at the same time. I already implemented a solution which worked on my test tomcat, but the JavaScript got cut out on the targetplatform, a WAS 8.0.0.9.

```
<c:if test="#{Bean.downloadPreconditions()}"> <!-- checks a simple boolean variable which gets set to 'true' after all informations for the download are set-->
            <script>
                window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById('form:download').onclick();
                }
            </script>

            <h:commandLink  id="download"
                            action="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{Bean.downloadFile}"></p:fileDownload> 
            </h:commandLink>
```

In this solution i start the download via JavaScript AFTER i redirected to the targetpage "bar.xhtml" from "foo.xhtml".

The PreRenderView solution does not work, because i visited the view before and it does not get freshly instantiated.

I tried several slightly different `PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);` version with an attached `<p:fileDownload>`, as well as a download invoked by a backingbean like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-provide-a-file-download-from-a-jsf-backing-bean).

I am aware that im trying to call 2 requests to the server with one single click. I want to know if it is still somehow possible to maybe first switch to the target view and after that call the download dialogue in an automated way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i still could not figure out why my JavaScript did not get executed properly, but i found a workaround:

Instead of calling the commandLink via proper JS at runtime, (Also note here: the commandLink needs to be defined above the JS, or as in my example a commandLink with the functionality already exists somewhere else on this site) I just invoked the link with the hardcoded primefaces syntax:

```
        <c:if test="#{Bean.downloadPreconditions()}"> <!-- checks a simple boolean variable which gets set to 'true' after all informations for the download are set-->                        
                    <script>
                        window.onload = function() {
                             var firstDownlink = document.getElementById("form:DownloadLink"); //this refers to a link, that already exists on my page, alternativly just create one but do not apply any visual effects to it so it stays hidden
                             firstDownlink.onclick.apply(firstDownlink);
                        }
                    </script>
        </c:if>
```