# Serve PDF i made with iText to the browser

Tags: jsp, servlets, browser, download, itext

I made a PDF in a java class that I want to be downloadable from the browser. I searched some solution online and I found the "servlet solution" but I don't understand how it works, what are request and response, how I generate them and how I can call the protected method. It would be nice if you can help me.

this is the method that generate the PDF (it works)

```
public void creaPDF(Persona p) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document doc=new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("/."));
    doc.open();
    PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(1);
    table.addCell(p.getCognome());
    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    doc.add(table);
    doc.close();
}
```

This is my first experience with jsp, servlet and all the other stuff, be patience.

Comment: My advise: try to get to know each new technology on its own. I.e. first follow some basic tutorial to get a simple servlet running on your server, something producing a simple hello world html output. Experiment around a bit with that setup, and as soon as you feel at home with that technology start integrating external libraries for creating formats like pdf.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I solved the situation yesterday.

Comment: If you solved it  - please answer your question here. What did you do? So you help all others...

Comment: i followed this suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-provide-a-file-download-from-a-jsf-backing-bean