# Maven resource filtering corrupts resource

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I have a pdf file in my Spring web app, inside folder webapp. I need an a href equivalent of JSF to download the file from the server.

I have tried these lines:

```
<h:link href="manual.pdf" >Download</h:link>
<h:outputLink value="manual.pdf" target="_blank">Download</h:outputLink>
```

The first one redirects to home and from the second I get a 404 error.

Please help, thanks in advance.

EDIT: It was suggested that this post [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-provide-a-file-download-from-a-jsf-backing-bean) might solve my problem but this is not true because while building the .war file my file inside the src/main/resources directory gets corrupted and is downloaded as blank pages. I moved the file to /webapp/WEB-INF in order to be able to download it using a "front end" solution.

EDIT 2: Assuming that it is a maven filtering problem as mentioned in a comment I edit the question so I you could help me.

In the pom.xml file there are the following lines:

```
resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

I proceeded making the below changes:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.pdf</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

Now my .war file does not containt manual.pdf at all and I get a

> FileNotFoundException: class path resource [manual.pdf] cannot be
>   resolved to URL because it does not exist

Could some one please help me understand how to exclude the resource from filtering and make it available for download **or alternatively** provide me with an other solution, a "front end" solution as mentioned in the original post, without having to go through back end code and resources.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it in WEB-INF and not in the ressources folder?

Comment: I edit my original post explaining what happens if I have the file in the resource directory. It actually almost doubles in size when I check it inside the .war file after mvn clean install and that possibly corrupts the file (pdf format) and is not able to open properly using any pdf reader application. I also checked it in a pdf validator and while the original file is valid, the file inside the .war after I build the project has errors.

Comment: Then it's actually not a jsf (nor spring) related question but a maven related one.

Comment: Maybe a maven resource filter has corrupted your PDF during build - you have to exclude *.pdf from filtering in your pom.xml.