# How to write xls file in java?

Tags: java, excel, file

I tried out this approach: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-provide-a-file-download-from-a-jsf-backing-bean/9394237#9394237)

It works fine with csv file, but i need to do the same for .xls file

In java side

```
public StringBuilder columnsForCsv(){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    columns.add("id");
    columns.add("from");
    columns.add("to");

    for(String column : columns){
        result.append(column + ",");
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code will create 3 different columns with name `id`  `from`  `to` in csv file

but when when i tried out the same for .xls file. This doesn't work.

Is there any way to write data in xls file without using any external library.

Comment: *"without using any external library"* just write one yourself. The only problem is that it'll take years to be of same quality as existing libraries.

Comment: @BalusC, i mean to say using only libraries given by java, is it possible or not. If yes, then how to do it.

Comment: .xls has been names by [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org) "horrible spreadsheet format" for good reason. .xlsx is XML, but is not simple. Better use POI.

Comment: Certainly it's possible :) Otherwise external libraries like Apache POI didn't exist. They are usually open source, you can just take a look in their source code to learn how they did it.