# Calling a link from a bean method to a button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This is on my bean, I am trying to call the link from this bean method.

```
 public void downloadXML() throws YDSException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
             Link = "http://localhost:8080/uberConsole/download?file=DEMODATA.xml";
```

This is on my primeface xhtml button.

```
  <p:button href="#{dbctoxmlProcessView.downloadXML()}" disabled="#{dbctoxmlProcessView.disable}"
  value="Download XML File" id="btnGenXML" 
                        icon="fa fa-fw fa-download" title="Download Generated XML"
 styleClass="ui-priority-primary"/>
```

Comment: Why not use and commandButton?

Comment: I have tried commandButton too but it still doesn't work.

Comment: <p:commandButton value="Download Xmlfile" id="btnGenXML" disabled="#{dbctoxmlProcessView.disable}" actionListener="#{dbctoxmlProcessView.downloadXML()}" update="tabConfigEventForm:frmEventXMLForm:eventxmlfrmdlg" 
                           ajax="false" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" icon="fa fa-fw fa-download" style="margin-left:-8px;"/>

Comment: This is the commandButton I used but it still doesn't work

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-provide-a-file-download-from-a-jsf-backing-bean

Comment: .. and https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml